# Flask session cookie disappears after refreshing the browser

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies, session-cookies, flask-login

I'm using Flask-Login to authenticate users for my website (ReactJS).
My Flask Backend automatically returns a set-cookie header after using 'login_user(user)'.
It then successfully sets a cookie in the browser. And it automatically sends this cookie with future requests.

However... When I refresh the browser, the cookie disappears which means the user is not authenticated anymore. The cookie shouldn't disappear after a refresh but I don't know how to achieve this.

Why is this happening and what's the solution?

Thanks